# Showing that f cannot be a linear fractional transformation

Tags: geometry

Let $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x+1}$. Show that f cannot be a linear fractional transformation. (Hint: do not try to argue that f cannot be put into the form of $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(1)=\frac 12=f(-1/2)$, while linear fractional transformations are all one-to-one.

Comment: so this shows that f cannot be a linear fractional transformation right?

Comment: This shows that $f$ is not one-to-one, yes.

Comment: This is a nice little exercise: to show a linear transformation is $\,1-1\,$...

Answer (score 2):

A linear fractional transformation sends lines in the complex plane into circles or lines. What happens to a line under this transformation? Does it always become another line or circle? Like the line $C(t) = it$?

Comment: What do you mean by $C(t)=it$?

Comment: A parametric equation for a curve in the plane. It is a line.